# How to physically bridge network interface KVM - Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm-virtualization

I have a host installed Linux/Ubuntu 10.04 LTS on a Dell PowerEdge server with 4 NICs interfaces, so how can I dedicate a network interface for Guest Machine ?

Comment: Why not simply bridge it? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to setup a network bridge interface on the host and have the virtual machines share the physical interface of the host. Although I am not certain about this, by default KVM uses NAT, so you have to manually configure the bridge. This involves installing some bridge related packages and modifying `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Please read this for a [step by step instructions](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Ubuntu_10.x_KVM_Networked_Bridge_Interface).

Comment: i already do this and this is my configuration, 'auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.0.236
network 192.168.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.253
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
auto br0
'

Answer (score 0):

If you use libvirt, you have to use the passthrough mode, as explained in http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#PCI_Passthrough_of_host_network_devices